# Append Rows before and after of another row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="thisTable">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<button onclick="prePend()">Insert Above</button>
<button onclick="appPend()">Inser Below</button>
```

On clicking some text input in this form, then on clicking buttons `Insert Above`/`Insert Below`, a new row is created in the position referenced by the focussed input.

Example: Click input in 2nd row, then click Insert Above button -- New row will be created above 2nd row. Need example function!

Comment: Google is full of people doing the same exercise.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is **not** a code writing service. We will help you with code you have written, but do **not** expect us to write the whole solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let currentIndex = $('#thisTable tbody tr').length - 1;
let staticHtml = ' <tr><td><input></td><td><input></td></tr>';

$('#thisTable').on('focus', 'input', function(){
  currentIndex = $(this).parent().parent().index() //Row index
});

function prePend() {
  changeStructure(currentIndex - 1);
}

function appPend() {
  changeStructure(currentIndex);
}

function changeStructure(index) {
  $('#thisTable > tbody > tr').eq(index).after(staticHtml);
  currentIndex++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="thisTable">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="prePend()">Insert Above</button>
<button onclick="appPend()">Inser Below</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, This is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using **JQUERY** :

References : [jQuery.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), [jQuery before](https://api.jquery.com/before/), [jQuery after](https://api.jquery.com/after/), [jQuery html](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

```js
var selectedinput;
document.addEventListener("focus",function(event){
    if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==="input"){
         selectedinput = event.target;
    }
},true);
function insert(pos)
{
    if(!selectedinput) return;
    var tr = $(selectedinput).closest("tr");
    pos=='above' ? tr.before(tr.html()) : tr.after(tr.html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="thisTable">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<button onclick="insert('above')">Insert Above</button>
<button onclick="insert('below')">Inser Below</button>
```

Using **JAVASCRIPT**:

References : [JS cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), [JS insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

```js
var selectedinput;
document.addEventListener("focus",function(event){
    if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==="input"){
         selectedinput = event.target;
    }
},true);
function insert(pos)
{
    if(!selectedinput) return;
    var tr = selectedinput.parentElement.parentElement;
    var elem = tr.cloneNode(true);
    //Clone node not supported in Opera - following can be used
    //var elem = document.createElement("tr")†;
    //elem.innerHTML=tr.innerHTML
    tr.insertAdjacentElement((pos=='above' ? 'beforeBegin':'afterEnd'),elem );
}
```

```html
<table id="thisTable">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<button onclick="insert('above')">Insert Above</button>
<button onclick="insert('below')">Inser Below</button>
```